# Call methods that usually gets called on new screen orientation

Tags: java, android, screen-orientation

I am working on an Android project right now that has been written by someone else. I noticed a bug where the code requests for a new screen orientation, not because it is needed, but because some views needs to be repositioned due to a `settings.xml` with its new positions.

Now I was wondering which methods get called exactly when a screen orientation is changed? I tried to get each view that needs to be drawn and invalidate it, because I thought that would result in the view being redrawn, but that didn't change the positioning of the view.

I did this:

```
int[] viewIds = {R.id.fooView, R.id.barView};

for (int i=1; i<viewIds.length; i++) {
    View v = findViewById(viewIds[i]);
    v.invalidate();
}
```

What would the correct way be to reposition the views after new position details are loaded from an xml?

Comment: Without further specifics, the easiest way would be to just invalidate() the view and let it rebuild itself.